# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 during debug

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, query-string

On page load I am extracting the parameter from the query string and inserting into the database.

here is the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConsString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS_TEST;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here is my aspx page coding

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Sample Configuration Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td>IP_Address:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="x" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MAC_Address:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="y" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The C# Code behind the aspx page is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Request.QueryString["x"] != null)
        {
            insertData();
        }

    }
    public void insertData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConsString"))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test(x, y) VALUES(@x, @y)", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("x", Request.QueryString["x"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("y", Request.QueryString["y"]));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }   
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
               // Console.WriteLine("Unable To Save Data. Error - " + Ex.Message);
                Response.Write("Unable To Save Data. Error - " + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now while executing it I am having error that *Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.*

I am not getting why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my own code after some research which is as follows and it worked..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Request.QueryString["x"] != null)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["y"] != null)
            {
                insertData();
            }
        }
     //   else
      //  {
     //         Response.Redirect("http://localhost:53627/Default.aspx");
     //   }


    }
    public void insertData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test(x, y) VALUES(@x, @y)", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("x", Request.QueryString["x"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("y", Request.QueryString["y"]));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }   
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
               // Console.WriteLine("Unable To Save Data. Error - " + Ex.Message);
                Response.Write("Unable To Save Data. Error - " + Ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConsString"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```